# AJAX error alert issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem with an ajax submit code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript" >
 $(function() {
 $(".submit").click(function() {

 var id                = $("#id").val();
 var name          = $("#name").val();
 var description = $("#description").val();

 var dataString = 'id='+ id + '&name='+ name + '&description=' + description;

 if(id=='' || name=='' || description==''){
 $('.alert-success').fadeIn(200).hide();
 $('.alert-danger').fadeOut(200).show();
 }
else {
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "?act=process",
data: dataString,

success: function() {
$('.alert-success').show();
setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "?"; }, 3000);
},

error: function() {
$('.alert-danger').show();
setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "?"; }, 3000);
}

});

}
return false;
});
});
</script>
```

I need to show both alerts and after 3 seconds hide and redirect.
The succes alert works properly but the error only appears and doesn't hide and redirect.

The HTML markup where this alerts appear looks like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable" style="display:none">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> Success!</div>

<div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissable" style="display:none">
<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button> Error</div>
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: url: "?act=process", that doesn't look right. It needs to be like url : '/url?act=process'

Comment: That url works fine. All data is passed well.

Comment: But why it does not redirect i actually dont see any errer lol

Comment: Ooh maybe return parameter in that error callback?

Comment: Oh and by the way `fadeIn()` already sets the `display` property to `block`. Using `show()` afterwards is pointless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If following does not work the problem is not because your script.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.ajax({
        url: '?act=process',
        type: 'post',
        data: {
            id: $id,
            name:$name,
            description:$description
        },
        success: function (result) {
            $('.alert-success').show();
            setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "http://youtube.com/"; }, 3000);
            console.log('Yay it worked');
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            $('.alert-danger').show();
            setTimeout(function () { window.location.href = "http://google.com/"; }, 3000);
            console.log('Something went wrong');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What was the problem? Did you track it?